# UITextField questions - input accessory and enumeration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield, enumeration

In my app, I have many different functions. These are view controllers that are all subclasses of my custom class, Function. By subclassing function, they inherit standard things like a background image, or the appropriate nav buttons.

My question is, can I put some code in function's viewDidLoad, that will enable it to set parameters for UITextFields in any controller that subclasses it. So basically is it possible to get all the properties of a class with a certain class (in this case UITextField)?

What I intend to do with this (apart from standardising the keyboards, setting the delegate etc.), is to create a UIToolbar with previous and next buttons on, which automatically takes you between text fields (without having to code it for each function). I know you can enumerate through text fields in the iOS simulator (by pressing tab), but is this an OS-wide thing?

Also if you could enumerate through text fields, I could make an app-wide hideKeyboard method and lots of other useful things...

Thanks in advance, I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` in your superclass.  Each subclass should be responsible for creating a list (NSArray) of the text fields.  Once you have that, you can tell if you are leaving the "last" text field, and go to the next controller.

If you want to "tab" to the next field, you can tag them (or keep them in a list) and use the delegate methods and `becomeFirstResponder` to change the "key field".

Comment: I don't quite understand, I don't want to switch controllers through this method, simply between text fields

Comment: OK thanks, but how do you actually go about creating the array, would you have to do it individually for each class or could you somehow implement some code in the superClass to do it?

Comment: Two options, abstractly search the view hierarchy for all UITextField objects or have each subclass explicitly build the list.